# Dropdown field in a form to populate a few hidden fields in a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm have an registration form for visitors to sign up for talks on my page.
The problem is that I have 4 different talks they can sign up for.
So I would like to have them select the talk they want to attend and store the talk details e.g. Date, Time and Session in separate fields.

The code below show me storing my talk sessions registered as:
 25th Nov 10:00am on EFFECTIVE LEARNING

I would like to have my confirmation email showing :

Date : 25th Nov

Time : 10:00am

Session : EFFECTIVE LEARNING

Would appreciate any help in this matter.

```
    <select class="validate-required" name="Session" placeholder="Your Session Choice" data-error-text="You need to select a Session to attend">
        <option selected="25th Nov  2:00pm on LEARNING MADE EASY" value="">Select</option>
        <option value="25th Nov 10:00am on EFFECTIVE LEARNING">EFFECTIVE LEARNING</option>
        <option value="25th Nov  2:00pm on LEARNING MADE EASY">LEARNING MADE EASY</option>
        <option value="26th Nov 10:00am on TURNING THE C's &amp; B's into A's">TURNING THE C's &amp; B's into A's</option>
        <option value="26th Nov  2:00pm on DRAWING OUT THE SPECIAL CHILD">DRAWING OUT THE SPECIAL CHILD</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: So where is your PHP code? Or do you expect us to do all the work for you?

Comment: this is way to early to ask this question.  Show us your Email code.

Comment: sorry guys. new here. don't know the procedure. thought since that part didn't work, it didn't make sense to put it up. learning. will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="validate-required" name="Session" id="sessions" placeholder="Your Session Choice" data-error-text="You need to select a Session to attend">
        <option value="0" selected>Select One</option>
        <option data-date="26th Nov" data-time="3:00pm" data-session="EFFECTIVE LEARNING" value="1">EFFECTIVE LEARNING</option>
        <option data-date="27th Nov" data-time="4:00pm" data-session="HTML Learning" value="2">LEARNING MADE EASY</option>
        <option data-date="28th Nov" data-time="5:00pm" data-session="JavaScript Learning" value="3">TURNING THE C's &amp; B's into A's</option>
        <option data-date="29th Nov" data-time="6:00pm" data-session="PHP Learning" value="4">DRAWING OUT THE SPECIAL CHILD</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("sessions").addEventListener("change", function(el){
        var value = document.getElementById('sessions').options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
        if (value != "0") {
            var session = document.getElementById('sessions').options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-session');
            var date = document.getElementById('sessions').options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-date');
            var time = document.getElementById('sessions').options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-time');
            alert('Session: '+session);
            alert('Date:'+date);
            alert('Time:'+time);
        } else {
            alert("You must select a valid option.");
        }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Try the above code inside body tag, You can  PHP echo out the date, time and session name into data-date, data-time and data-session respectively. Now, you can get it by adding event listener, by selecting element, targeting options(selected), and get its data attributes.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind sharing. Works perfectly.